# How to change a line after read a line in file?

Tags: c, file, fseek

This is my code. read a line and change it.

```
    char buf[SIZE];
    while (fgets(buf,SIZE,fp) != NULL)
    {
        to_upper(buf);   
        fseek(fp,-1L,SEEK_CUR);
        fputs(buf,fp);
        fseek(fp,1L,SEEK_CUR);
    }
```

I know that I can create another file to implement, I want to konw why the code doesn't work?

Comment: You have to call `fflush(fp)` when you switch between reading and writing.

Comment: Note that this will only work if you don't change the length of the line.

Comment: You'd need to capture the current read position before calling `fgets()`; you'd then need to set that position (your code rewinds by one byte, not one line), and then write.  The seek after writing moves the pointer one byte beyond the last byte written.  It is important to do a seek between reading and writing and between writing and reading.

Comment: @kang kang, To achieve converting a file to upper case, there is no need to read line-by-line.  Use `fread()/fwrite()` to change a block of data per iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107048/how-to-change-a-line-after-read-a-line-in-file#comment135930586_77107048), you need to capture the current read position before calling `fgets()`; then you reset that position and write the revised data, and you need a seek of some sort after the write so that you can read again.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void to_upper(char *buffer)
{
    unsigned char u;

    while ((u = *buffer) != '\0')
        *buffer++ = toupper(u);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *fname = "input.txt";
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2)
        fname = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r+");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s' for read/write: %d %s\n",
                argv[0], fname, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    long pos = ftell(fp);

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
    {
        to_upper(buffer);
        fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);
        fputs(buffer, fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        pos = ftell(fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The error checking after the open succeeds is non-existent, but the checking before that is crucial to safe operation.

The C standard [§7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function ¶7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7) says:

> When a file is opened with update mode ('`+`' as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

The code shown is careful to use the 'no-op' `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR)` call after the write and before the next read.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. We need to remember the before and after positions of each line. Doing an `fseek` by one character position doesn't work. That's because we're reading an entire line (that is of varying length).
2. While we *can* do `fputs` in this particular instance, it's somewhat hazardous. Better to just do `fputc`.
3. Note that the code works because doing `read/seek/write` needs an `fflush` but here we're doing `read/seek/write/seek` so no `fflush` is needed.

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char buf[10000];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"need filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(*argv,"r+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(*argv);
        exit(1);
    }

    long posbef = 0;

    while (1) {
        // get a line
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp) == NULL)
            break;

        // get starting position of next line
        long posaft = ftell(fp);

        // get first char of line and convert to uppercase
        int chr = buf[0];
        chr = toupper((unsigned char) chr);

        // seek [back] to start of current line
        fseek(fp,posbef,SEEK_SET);

        // output updated character
        fputc(chr,fp);

        // ensure the char is output (?)
        // need fflush after an output and before an input
#if 0
        fflush(fp);
#endif

        // seek to the start of the next line
        fseek(fp,posaft,SEEK_SET);

        // this is now the start position of the current line for the next
        // loop iteration
        posbef = posaft;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```